# Get safes owned by an owner's address on L2 chains

Tags: gnosis-safe

According to the step 2 in docs here: https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4971293-i-don-t-remember-my-safe-address-where-can-i-find-it, an API end point can be used to get safe address if we have an owner's address. But this API endpoint seems to be only working for Ethereum. What's the API end point for L2 chains?

Comment: I highly doubt there is such an endpoint. There are lots of different L2s out there - you have to query them individually somehow, probably not through Gnosis APIs.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Gnosis safe itself supports multiple L2 chains right, I'm referring to APIs for those